# Puppeteer / Node - Target.createTarget - Target Closed

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using Node/Puppeteer in the code below, passing in a large list of URL's for traversal and scraping. It has been difficult to do it asynchronously, though I find that I am getting closer and closer to the answer. I am currently stuck on an issue related to the following error.

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 17): Error: Protocol error (Target.createTarget): Target closed.`

This error occurs once upon every iteration of the while loop. Though I'm not sure what I may be doing incorrectly.

Could someone help me do the following:
 1) Diagnose the source of the error. 
 2) Potentially find a more effective way to traverse a large list of URLs asynchronously.

```
async function subProc(list, batchSize) {
let subList = null;
let i = 0;

while (list.length > 0) {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    subList = list.splice(0, batchSize);
    console.log("Master List Size :: " + list.length);
    console.log("SubList Size :: " + subList.length);

    for (let j = 0; j < subList.length; j++) {
        promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(pageScrape(subList[j], browser));
        }));
    }
    Promise.all(promiseArray)
        .then(response => {
            procArray.concat(response);
        });
    promiseArray = new Array();
    try {
        await browser.close();
    } catch(ex){
        console.log(ex);
    }
};
}

async function pageScrape(url, browser) {
let page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url, {
    timeout: 0
});
await page.waitFor(1000);
return await page.evaluate(() => {
    let appTitle = document.querySelector('').innerText;
    let companyName = document.querySelector('').innerText;
    let dateListed = document.evaluate("", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerText;
    let category = document.evaluate("']//a//strong", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerText;
    /*  */
    return {
        appTitle,
        companyName,
        dateListed,
        category
    }
}).then(response => {
    let urlData = {
        id: subList[j],
        appName: response.appTitle,
        companyName: response.companyName,
        dateListed: response.dateListed,
        category: response.category
    }
    return urlData;
});
```

};

Comment: Definitely, you should add `await` before `Promise.all(promiseArray)`. Can you give us sample off all the code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution to the problem I was having.
Every computer is limited in its processing ability, so instead of iterating through 1000 urls simultaneously you have to break it down into smaller pieces.

By using a PromiseAll, and iterating and scraping 10 urls at a time and storing these values in an array, I was able to throttle the processing required to iterate through all 1000 urls.

```
 processBatch(subData, 10, procArray).then((processed)=>{
            for(let i = 0; i < procArray.length; i++){
                for(let j = 0; j < procArray[i].length; j++){
                   results.push(procArray[i][j]);
                }
            }

 function processBatch(masterList, batchSize, procArray){
    return Promise.all(masterList.splice(0, batchSize).map(async url => 
    {
    return singleScrape(url)
    })).then((results) => {
    if (masterList.length < batchSize) {
        console.log('done');
        procArray.push(results);
        return procArray;
    } else {
        console.log('MasterList Size :: ' + masterList.length);
        procArray.push(results);
        return processBatch(masterList, batchSize, procArray);
    }
   })
 }
```